# How do I make the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin and the Maven Checkstyle plugin use the same rules?

Tags: eclipse, maven, checkstyle

I'd like the Checkstyle rules in Eclipse match the rules when my Maven build runs on Jenkins.

How do I go about that?

Thanks.

[edit]

So I exported the checkstyle settings in eclipse to a new XML file in the project folder and pointed the maven checkstyle plugin at that with

```
<plugin>
 <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.6</version>
 <configuration>
    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It's good that you posted the sample code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to export your eclipse checkstyle settings into a file and configure your Jenkin (/Hudson) checkstyle plugin to use the same configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I did it as followed: I have a separate maven build project that contains checkstyle/pmd and others stuff (rule sets) on the classpath.
Add this project as dependency in the checkstyle/pmd plugin configuration in your pom, and it will work in maven and in jenkins/hudson if you simple call the maven checkstyle/pmd goal.
Works like a charm.